# c# specify method invocation based upon input?

Tags: c#, delegates, system.reflection

How would one best go about allowing the input of a c# program to control method invocation? For example:

Assume we have a delegate type:

```
delegate void WriteMe();
```

And a couple of methods:

```
void PrintInt() { Console.WriteLine(10); }
void PrintString() { Console.WriteLine("Hello world."); }
```

And allowing the input to select the invocation order:

```
public static WriteMe ProcessInvocationInput(int[] val) {
    WriteMe d = null; 
    foreach (int i in val) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1: d += PrintInt; break; 
            case 2: d += PrintString; break; 
        } 
    }
}
```

And the code that calls it all:

```
static void Main(string args[]) {
    int[] values = {1, 2, 3}; // Obviously this array could be filled 
                              // from actual input (args, file, wherever)
    WriteMe d = ProcessInvocationInput(values); 

    d(); 
}
```

The reason I'm posting this question is because it seems rather complex to implement what seems like a simple idea. I know another way to accomplish this behavior is with the reflection API, but that would be even more convoluted.

Comment: Are you planning on choosing methods based on the type or based on the value?

Comment: Based on value (in my example of the int[] given to ProcessInvocationInput).

Comment: Your code works. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on the scope you're trying to cover. For simple cases you could use a switch (I'd suggest and enum to make it clear):

```
enum InputCommands
{
    PrintHelloWorld = 1,
    ExecuteFixedBinary = 2,
    ...
}

switch((InputCommands)inputInt)
{
    case InputCommands.PrintHelloWorld: ...
    case InputCommands.ExecuteFixedBinary: ...
}
```

But if you're writing a shell, than you need something more robust, like some sort of `IExecutableCommand` interface implemented by various classes.

```
interface IExecutableCommand
{
    void Execute(string arg);
}
```

You will have to implement some parser to handle multiple invocation requests and/or handle more complex arguments.

If you want to use Reflection, be sure to validate your input! That could be done by only executing methods with a custom attribute on them.

```
class ExecutableMethodAttribute : Attribute { }

[ExecutableMethod]
void Foo() 
{ 
   ...
}
```

Filtering out methods with this attribute is easy enough:

```
someAssembly.GetTypes()
  .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
  .Where(mi => mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExecutableMethodAttribute), true).Any())
```

Comment: Thank you, this tells me exactly what I need to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ICollection<Action> ProcessInvocationInput(int[] val)
{
    var actions = new List<Action>();
    foreach (int i in val)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1: actions.Add(PrintInt);
            case 2: actions.Add(PrintString);
        }
    }

    return actions;
}

...
foreach (var action in ProcessInvocationInput(input))
{
    action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a dictionary of values to Actions you can do

```
 private static Dictionary<int,Action> _actions=new Dictionary<int,Actions> {
     {1, PrintInt},
     {2, PrintString},
 };
```

Then you can just loop and process

```
foreach (var item in input) _actions[item]();
```